# how to upgrade operating system of micromax E311 device for a novice user

Tags: rooting, updates, fastboot

I have Micromax E311 phone.

For some reason the settings of phone have become unreachable. So on the display I see com.android.settings. Setting icon with a mechanical gear on it but when I tap it then I get a pop up

> Unfortunately, Settings has stopped.

I clicked Ok.

Then again the same message pops up within a fraction of second this keeps happening then I restart the phone somehow and if I touch settings then same thing happens. If I don't touch the setting's icon, there is no problem I can keep using the phone.

So I am not sure what is the OS in this phone. My guess is that it has been formatted to the factory settings, so it's having Android 4.4.2. I read many tutorials about rooting the phone and installing custom ROM on it. Like

> After rooting an Android phone, you can switch the operating system
>   ROM whenever you want. The rooting process removes the preinstalled
>   operating system on the Android phone, replacing it with a rooted
>   Android OS.

as given on https://smallbusiness.chron.com/change-roms-rooted-android-30006.html

How to root any device
https://www.xda-developers.com/root/

How to install custom rom 
https://www.xda-developers.com/how-to-install-custom-rom-android/
For my device flash rom
https://www.gogorapid.com/flash-stock-rom-on-micromax-e311/

What I am confused with is to upgrade my device OS to android 10, first I should replace the ROM and then do "something"  as mentioned on lot of forums or what exactly I should to to upgrade the OS of my phone.
I am very confused with all the tutorials available on internet.
I want to know simple steps in bullet points like

- Step 1 change ROM
- Step 2 change this
- Step 3 change that
- Step 4 boot phone.

Meaning such a guideline will help me when I read tutorials, and I was getting confused with them.I am not sure if with android 4 OS I can directly upgrade to some thing like android 9 or so.

Comment: You are confused because you are reading generic tutorials and background articles. On Android however every device is special, hence unless you have a tutorial that is specific for your device the tutorial is useless.

Comment: The first step is to find a custom ROM based on Android 10 that is made specifically for Micromax E311, which doesn't look like there is. The latest Android version that I could find is Android 6.0 Marshmallow, which doesn't look stable either. Browse [XDA Forum for this specific model](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/micromax-nitro-2) for more information.

Comment: actually the model I fear is not Nitro. I have lost access to settings some how before that I had rooted the phone, so if I can know exactly which model number or OS this phone is running some how by connecting with USB cable with a laptop, I will explore more but I do not know how. Thanks for your XDA forum link I will post in it I was not able to search that forum device specific. Well as I am a novice user and do not have much post count so I can not post in that link you gave. That is developer forum so they locked it for spamming by non technical posts.

Comment: ok I have posted the question [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/general/upgrading-os-micromax-e311-t4107655) on XDA users. I posted the link so that if some one else comes here they may see that link. However mostly my questions never get any response on XDA forum.